# Razor Engine Template Parsing Error- Expression Too long or complex to compile

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, razor

We are getting Expression too long or complex error while trying to parse simple HTML page. 
Following is the error:

> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown
>   by the target of an invocation. --->
>   RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateCompilationException: Unable to compile
>   template. An expression is too long or complex to compile
>
> Other compilation errors may have occurred. Check the Errors property
>   for more information.    at
>   RazorEngine.Compilation.DirectCompilerServiceBase.CompileType(TypeContext
>   context) in
>   c:_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Compilation\DirectCompilerServiceBase.cs:line
>   100    at
>   RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplateType(String
>   razorTemplate, Type modelType) in
>   c:_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line
>   256    at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.CreateTemplate(String
>   razorTemplate, Type templateType, Object model) in
>   c:_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line
>   127    at RazorEngine.Templating.TemplateService.Parse(String
>   razorTemplate, Object model, DynamicViewBag viewBag, String cacheName)
>   in
>   c:_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Templating\TemplateService.cs:line
>   435    at RazorEngine.Razor.Parse[T](String razorTemplate, T model) in
>   c:_git\RazorEngine\src\Core\RazorEngine.Core\Razor.cs:line 263

Comment: It would help to see the simple page :)

Comment: Or tell us what you have done that is not standard, extra Nuget packages for example?

Comment: Have done nothing that is not standard. Funny thing is i wrote another application which just parses same page and it works fine. So now I am not sure if it's Parsing that's causing error or the content i am passing are too complex? Any idea what could be too long or complex for Razor to parse? is there any limit?

Comment: Add that as an answer and accept it please. A comment is not the place for the resolution of an issue.

Comment: Thanks. I posted as an answer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was solved by using Razor.Compile first and then Razor.Run. When you use Razor.Parse it will create one dll file and will never dispose it. We were performing stress test on server and ended up with millions of unknown dll files which were created by Razor in Temp folder. By using Compile first you are only creating one dll file. Razor.Run will just use compile template and Parse templates.

Comment: I used first Razor.Compile and then Razor.Run, but still I get this error while compiling: An expression is too long or complex to compile, and is not pointing me where exactly is that expression in my .cshtml file. Any ideas?